# Multi - Insert on Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have this **Cluster_Members** model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cluster_Members extends Model
{
    protected $table ='cluster_members';
    protected $fillable=['client_id','cluste_id'];
    public function name(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client_Information','client_id');
    }


}
```

Then i have check in my view that has name of **client_id[]**

In my controller. I want to insert it once and detect if the cluster_id and client_id is not existing on that table.

Any suggestion on how to do it without looping like this?

```
$cluster_members = new \App\Cluster_Members;
$cluster_id= $request->id
foreach($request->client_id as $x){
   $cluster_members::Create(['cluster_id'=>$cluster_id,'client_id'=>$x]);
}
```

Comment: check this two method firstOrCreate() and firstOrNew()

Comment: Is it a good practice to loop and use **$cluster_members::firstOrCreate()**?

Comment: You can insert multiple array using Model::insert($data); where $data is a array of your data like below 
$data = array(
    array('cluster_id'=>'cluster_id 1', 'client_id'=> 3),
    array('cluster_id'=>'cluster_id 2', 'client_id'=> 4),
    //...
);

But you can't check that the data is exists or not. So I think you have to go through loop.